# Ruby: Swap out hash key with matching value from other hash

Tags: ruby, hash, replace

I have these hashes:

```
hash  = {1 => "popcorn", 2 => "soda"}
other_hash = {1 => "dave", 2 => "linda", 3 => "bobby_third_wheel"}
```

I would like to replace the id reference with the name associated to the id in the second hash, if there is a record in `other_hash` that has nothing to match, it should just be dropped in the resulting hash. Like this:

```
the_one_hash_to_rule_them_all = {"dave" => "popcorn", "linda" => "soda"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an "array-comprehension" with the pattern `enumerable.map { expr if condition }.compact` and finally an `Array#to_h`.

```
h = other_hash.map { |k, v| [v, hash[k]] if hash.has_key?(k) }.compact.to_h
#=> {"dave"=>"popcorn", "linda"=>"soda"}
```

Also:

```
h = other_hash.select { |k, v| hash.has_key?(k) }.map { |k, v| [v, hash[k]] }.to_h
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! thank you so much. I want to name this question better. I feel that people will want to at some stage do this. how could I improve it? I was going to use replace hash key with another hash value. but there is a replace method that will do terrible things.

Comment: Note that `Array#to_h` is available from Ruby 2.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can easly use this `each_with_object` method on "primary" hash with names.

```
other_hash.each_with_object({}) { |(id, name), h| h[name] = hash[id] if hash.key?(id) }
# => {"dave"=>"popcorn", "linda"=>"soda"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
hash.each_with_object({}){|(k,v), res| res[other_hash[k]] = v}
# => {"dave"=>"popcorn", "linda"=>"soda"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hash.map{|k, v| [other_hash[k], v]}.to_h
# => {"dave"=>"popcorn", "linda"=>"soda"}
```

Comment: In lower ruby versions use `Hash[hash.map{|k, v| [other_hash[k], v]}]`